# OrientDB. Connection leaks or just not closing connections

Tags: java, orientdb

We have a large multithreaded Java EE application running on Wildfly 8.
We are using OrientDB 2.1.19.

And we have some problems with the connection leaks. At some point orient server stops responding and all threads working with db stuck on retrieving new connection.

Configuration is following:

```
OGlobalConfiguration.CLIENT_CONNECT_POOL_WAIT_TIMEOUT.setValue(5000);
OGlobalConfiguration.CLIENT_DB_RELEASE_WAIT_TIMEOUT.setValue(5000);
OGlobalConfiguration.CLIENT_CHANNEL_MAX_POOL.setValue(1000);
OGlobalConfiguration.DB_POOL_MIN.setValue(100);
OGlobalConfiguration.DB_POOL_MAX.setValue(5000);
OGlobalConfiguration.STORAGE_LOCK_TIMEOUT.setValue(5000);
OGlobalConfiguration.DB_POOL_IDLE_TIMEOUT.setValue(5000);
OGlobalConfiguration.DB_POOL_IDLE_CHECK_DELAY.setValue(1000);
```

OPartitionedDatabasePool we're getting thru OPartitionedDatabasePoolFactory

```
poolFactory = new OPartitionedDatabasePoolFactory();
documentPool = poolFactory.get(orientDBPath, username, password);
```

Then depending on our needs we are using ODatabaseDocumentTx or OObjectDatabaseTx using

```
documentPool.acquire();
```

Acquired ODatabaseDocumentTx or OObjectDatabaseTx we are passing to so called executor, which executes Runnable or Callable.

```
public void run(ORunnable<DB> oRunnable) {
    // db is the private member of executor containing acquired db.
    try {
        //...
        oRunnable.run(db);          
        //...
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        if(!db.isClosed()) {
            db.close();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see we are closing db in finally section, also we are fully detaching all documents recieved from db. But in some cases number of connections to DB is not dropping and after that we're getting following exception

```
    2016-07-28 23:10:45,957 FINE  [com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.ORemoteConnectionManager] (default task-46) Network connection pool is receiving a closed connection to reuse: discard it
2016-07-28 23:10:45,957 FINE  [com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.ORemoteConnectionManager] (default task-46) Cannot unlock connection lock: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:155) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1260) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:460) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
  at com.orientechnologies.common.concur.lock.OAdaptiveLock.unlock(OAdaptiveLock.java:123) [orientdb-core-2.1.19.jar:2.1.19]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.unlock(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:371) [orientdb-enterprise-2.1.19.jar:2.1.19]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.ORemoteConnectionManager.remove(ORemoteConnectionManager.java:128) [orientdb-client-2.1.19.jar:2.1.19]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.ORemoteConnectionManager.release(ORemoteConnectionManager.java:119) [orientdb-client-2.1.19.jar:2.1.19]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.endResponse(OStorageRemote.java:1643) [orientdb-client-2.1.19.jar:2.1.19]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.command(OStorageRemote.java:1240) [orientdb-client-2.1.19.jar:2.1.19]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemoteThread.command(OStorageRemoteThread.java:453) [orientdb-client-2.1.19.jar:2.1.19]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLQuery.run(OSQLQuery.java:72) [orientdb-core-2.1.19.jar:2.1.19]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery.run(OSQLSynchQuery.java:85) [orientdb-core-2.1.19.jar:2.1.19]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.query.OQueryAbstract.execute(OQueryAbstract.java:33) [orientdb-core-2.1.19.jar:2.1.19]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.query(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:717) [orientdb-core-2.1.19.jar:2.1.19]
```

Here is the piece of code for the exception above

```
ODocument storedSession = orient.onDocuments().call(new ODocCallable<ODocument>() {
                    @Override
                    public ODocument call(ODatabaseDocumentTx db) {
                        try {
                            List<ODocument> list = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>("select from " + CLAZZ + " where storedSession_sessionID = ?"), sessionId);

                            if (list.isEmpty()){
                                return null;
                            }
                            return documentUnpin(list.get(0));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // PersistentSession may not be in DB on request (for example in workspaces)
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });
```

Any suggestions how to improve the situation with connections?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you post more code related to the above stack where a query has been executed ?

Comment: @AlessandroRota, I've posted piece of code causing the exception. onDocuments() function returns ODatabaseDocumentTx, which's passed as a function param db.

Comment: can you check if the threads are terminating properly and also releasing the connections ? Also from your snippets it looks like the `ODocCallable` is not context aware , thus the threads created by your application are not managed by the application server , so i don't think you could find easily what is happening if many of them are getting spawned and got bugged when trying to acquire connection so it might creating concurrency issues due to managed resources / unmanaged threads combination.